# How to reindex data with shell_exec cron magento

Tags: cache, reindex

```
$indexer="/var/www/clients/client1/web38/web/shell/indexer.php";  
if(file_exists($indexer))  
{  
            $idxlist=array("catalog_product_attribute",  
                           "catalog_product_price",  
                           "catalog_product_flat",  
                           "catalog_category_flat",  
                           "catalog_category_product",  
                           "catalog_url",  
                           "catalogsearch_fulltext",  
                           "cataloginventory_stock");  
    //reindex using magento command line  
    foreach($idxlist as $idx)  
    {  
        echo "reindex $idx \n ";  
        shell_exec("php /var/www/clients/client1/web38/web/shell/indexer.php --reindex $idx"); 

OR
    exec("php /var/www/clients/client1/web38/web/shell/indexer.php --reindex $idx");
```

Re-indexing is not working with this way , what issue in my code , please tell me suggestion.

Comment: try `php -f /var/www/clients/client1/web38/web/shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_attribute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be `shell_exec` not allowed in your php ini.

You can use this code instead of shell command. You have to create a file on your magento root and hit from browser.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
umask(0);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
    $process->reindexAll();
}
```

Comment: Hi Ashish , this way is taking time to execute , i want to with commend line in php page , is it possible or not ?. thank you for your help

Comment: In that case you have to enable `shell_exec` at your server.

Comment: but this exec() function also require to enable at server ?

Comment: Yes, Its required